# Why do I keep getting an error when trying to install gulp?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, npm-install

for some reason I am unable to install gulp, it always brings up this error:

```
    /wp-content/themes/the-advocates-theme$ npm i gulp-install

added 4 packages, and audited 755 packages in 2s

39 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

12 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 6 high, 3 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

and this is what I get when I run `npm audit`:

```
glob-parent  <5.1.2
Severity: high
Regular expression denial of service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-ww39-953v-wcq6
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install gulp@3.9.1, which is a breaking change
node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/glob-parent
node_modules/glob-watcher/node_modules/glob-parent
  chokidar  1.0.0-rc1 - 2.1.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/glob-watcher/node_modules/chokidar
    glob-watcher  >=3.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
    node_modules/glob-watcher
  glob-stream  5.3.0 - 6.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/glob-stream
    vinyl-fs  >=2.4.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-stream
    node_modules/vinyl-fs
      gulp  >=4.0.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of vinyl-fs
      node_modules/gulp

lodash.template  <4.5.0
Severity: critical
Prototype Pollution in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-jf85-cpcp-j695
No fix available
node_modules/lodash.template
  gulp-util  >=1.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of lodash.template
  node_modules/gulp-util
    gulp-install  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of gulp-util
    node_modules/gulp-install

postcss  <8.2.13
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service in postcss - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-566m-qj78-rww5
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install gulp-sourcemaps@2.6.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/@gulp-sourcemaps/identity-map/node_modules/postcss
  @gulp-sourcemaps/identity-map  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/@gulp-sourcemaps/identity-map
    gulp-sourcemaps  >=3.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @gulp-sourcemaps/identity-map
    node_modules/gulp-sourcemaps

12 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 6 high, 3 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```

Comment: When I run gulp, it doesn't work, but when running npm run watch DOES work and it does compile all my SCSS and JS.

Answer (score 3):

Those are not errors, they are warnings issued by npm. The gulp team is aware of those warnings but has decided that they do not need to be regarded.
Instead, they insist that [`npm audit` is broken](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2201#issuecomment-401614368) and should be fixed. You may ask them to change their minds, but beware that your request would be likely flagged as spam: [1](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2591), [2](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2587), [3](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2607#issuecomment-880451463).

Comment: The issues is that when I run `gulp` on terminal it throws an error and it says Module not found.

Comment: @fjimenez You should show that error in the question.